# how to post xml data using groovy httpbuilder

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I'm trying to send some XML which contains namespaces using HttpBuilder as follows:

```
new HTTPBuilder(URL).client.request(POST, XML) {
  body = '<foo:bar xmlns:foo="http://example.com/foo"></foo:bar>'
}
```

If I remove the namespace it succeeds.

What is the right way to send namespaces using Groovy HttpBuilder?

**EDIT:**

The error message when using the namespace looks like this:

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Error parsing
>   'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' response org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>           at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)

**EDIT 2:**

The XML can be sent without any problem using various other HTTP clients (Postman, curl, vs-code rest-client)

Comment: How exactly it "unsucceedes",if you don't remove the NS?

Comment: @injecteer: I've added an example output. Thanks for helping me to clarify the question!

Comment: shouldn't that error occur on receiving side? HttpBuilder itself doesn't give a damn about parsing XML while sending.

Comment: @injecteer: Oddly enough it occurs on the sending side. There is no notion of java on the receiving side. I don't know if it checks the namespace or what but it is related. Also, I suspect HttpBuilder does care because if I send the exact same message using POSTMAN, curl or HttpClient there are no issues.

Comment: try changing `XML` to `TEXT` and set the header instead: `headers =  [Accept : 'application/xml']`, thus the HttpBuilder would ignore XML nature

Comment: @injecteer. Another good suggestion. However, the end point is must then handle it differently when receiving it (convert text to xml) and all other clients would have to send text instead of XML. However, I will try and see if it helps.